# Grep files in subdirectories and write out files for each directory

Tags: linux, grep, bioinformatics

I am working on a bioinformatics workflow in which the tool in question, 'salmon' creates multiple directories having a 'quant.sf' file. I want to find all 'lnc' entries within these files and save them as 'lnc.sf' for all directories.
I was previously running
`cat quant.sf | grep 'lnc' > lnc.sf`
in all directories individually that seemed to solve my problem. Now I want to write a script that goes into each directory and generates a lnc.sf file.
I have tried doing

```
find . -name "quant.sf" | while read A
do 
cat $A | grep 'lnc' > lnc.sf
done
```

But this just creates a concatenated lnc.sf file in the current directory. Any help is highly appreciated.
Thank You!

Comment: The redirection is writing to the current folder, but you want to write to `$A` folder, right? Then prepend the `$A` folder to the file you are creating: `... > $(dirname "$A")/lnc.sf`

Answer (score 1):

If all your `quant.sf` files are at the same hierarchy level, the following should work, assuming a folder structure like `month/day/quant.sf`:

```
grep -h 'lnc' */*/quant.sf > lnc.sf
```

Otherwise, find the files, be aware of using find+read instead of exec or xargs; understand variable expansion with whitespaces, get rid of the redundant `cat` process, and write the file to the correct directory:

```
find . -name 'quant.sf' | while IFS= read -r A
do 
  grep 'lnc' "$A" > "${A%/*}/lnc.sf"
done
```

If you have GNU find + xargs, use `-print0` combined with `-0`:

```
find . -name 'quant.sf' -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 sh -c 'grep "lnc" "$1" > "${1%/*}/lnc.sf"' -
```

Or use `-exec` of find, which avoids problems with weird files names:

```
find . -name 'quant.sf' -exec sh -c 'grep "lnc" "$1" > "${1%/*}/lnc.sf"' - ';'
```